# Have no idea what this sentence means

Tags: expressions, terminology, acronyms

It's from a tweet. I mean, I get what the story is about, but I have no idea what the sentence in bold type means. It's cryptic to me.

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/jmartNYT/status/1402249152248045569)

**The info flow/expectation setting w medium info Ds on this was problematic**

@MTPFirstRead

> “HR 1 designed as a messaging bill.... And now Democrats have an activist base that’s upset and disappointed – over a bill that never had a chance for passage in a 50-50 Senate”

Comment: I have no idea. Those NYT people need to write clearer English. It is very annoying.

Comment: I doubt parsing poorly written tweets is going to be of much use to any future readers. Is there a particular part or construction of this garbled mess that you think might help someone understand English better if it were explained?

Comment: Don’t try to learn English from Twitter.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence is highly abbreviated (and they've left out some helpful punctuation that wouldn't even have added to the character count!).  Here is the expanded version:

> The information flow and expectation setting with medium-information Democrats on this [bill] was problematic.

What the writer means by *medium-information Democrats* is people who are dependent on *high-information Democrats* (i.e., politicians and pundits who pay very careful attention to legislation) to provide them with some amount of *information flow* and to help to *set expectations* about the likelihood of success of this particular bill.  In this case, the *information flow* and *expectation setting* was not done competently - it was *problematic*.